# Android Is An Intent Unique To An Activity or Global

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm curious as to whether an intent is unique to a set activity or not.

For example, my current usage of an intent is to give it some data from Activity 1 and pass it on to Activity 2.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("id", id.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("weight", weight.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("zipTo", zipTo.getText().toString());
        intent.putExtra("locationId", locationID.getSelectedItem().toString());
        intent.putExtra("imageNum", 1);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Now, in MainActivity I can use the following code to retrieve the data passed from the previous activity.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        id = bundle.getString("id");
        weight = bundle.getString("weight");
        locationID = bundle.getString("locationID");
        zipTo = bundle.getString("zipTo");
```

After doing some work in MainActivity, I need to return to the previous activity that sent us to MainActivity (and I need the data that was originally sent to return).

Do I need to redefine an intent, and do "intent.putExtra" for each value again in MainActivity before sending it to the first Activity? Or is the intent global, and once defined in one activity I can use it in the others with getIntent().getExtras()?

Comment: "Or is the intent global" -- no, it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intents are not global.  You only have access to the bundle in the activity you started with the intent passed.

You should use startActivityForResult(intent).  This provides the behavior youre looking for.

[Getting a result from an activity](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

The idea is you start the new intent. In this case 'MainActivity'.  Once you are done with your logic in MainActivity you use the strategy above to pass a result back to the activity that started MainActivity.

Comment: Wow, can't believe I glossed over that. That's exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

information passed through intents are not global from one activity to another, what is global is shared preferences and information that is metadata which is stored in manifest.xml.